# tab activity in android

Tags: android, tabview

Hi i am new to this "Tab Activity" concepts .I searched for this and finally i come to know that i should implement "Fragments" .I done the following code,but it is showing error.,Please guide me to solve this.

```
public class VendorActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vendor);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


         // Tab for Photos

        TabSpec photospec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("Photos");
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, Simple.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);


        System.out.println("b4 fragment");
        TabSpec songspec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
        songspec.setIndicator("Songs");
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);
        System.out.println("bafter fragment");

        System.out.println("1");
        mTabHost.addTab(photospec); // Error comes here.android
        System.out.println("2");
        mTabHost.addTab(songspec); 
        System.out.println("3");

//       mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
//                  FragmentStackSupport.sim.class, null);





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_vendor, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

My logcat:

```
03-29 23:44:09.245: I/Process(447): Sending signal. PID: 447 SIG: 9
03-29 23:46:17.304: I/System.out(474): b4 fragment
03-29 23:46:17.304: I/System.out(474): bafter fragment
03-29 23:46:17.304: I/System.out(474): 1
03-29 23:46:17.444: D/AndroidRuntime(474): Shutting down VM
03-29 23:46:17.444: W/dalvikvm(474): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vegetable/com.vegetable.VendorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:209)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.vegetable.VendorActivity.onCreate(VendorActivity.java:50)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-29 23:46:17.584: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try learn about Fragments first http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Please point out which is line 50 of your `VendorActivity`, as we have no way to know.

Comment: Thanks @Pragnani surely i will go through the tutorial..Can you say what i am doing wrong..

Comment: @CommonsWare in my post i have specified  Error comes here.android

Answer (score 0):

`mTabHost` is `null`.

Apparently, that is because `res/layout/activity_vendor.xml` does not contain a `FragmentTabHost` named `@android:id/tabhost`, which is what your `findViewById()` call is requesting.

Comment: @Subburaj: You can try cleaning your project (in Eclipse, Project > Clean; at the command line, `ant clean`) and see if that helps. Otherwise, something is out of sync between your XML, your Java code, and your stack trace.